# Is there something that I should add,I got stuck for hours

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to access to http://localhost:4200/Personnes/view/:2 but I go the error (ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nom' of undefined)

"My personnnes.service.component.ts"

```
`export class PersonnesService {
baseUrl='http://localhost/api' ;
personnes: Personne[] = [] ;

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

getAll():Observable<Personne[]>{
return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/list`).pipe(
map((res)=>{
this.personnes=res['data'] ;
return this.personnes ;
}),
catchError(this.handleError)) ;
} ;

private handleError(error :HttpErrorResponse){
console.log(error) ;
return throwError('Erreur sur qlq chose.') ; 
}

store(personne: Personne): Observable<Personne[]> {
return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/store`, { data: personne }) 
.pipe(map((res) => {
this.personnes.push(res['data']);
return this.personnes;
}),
catchError(this.handleError));
}

getSinglePersonne(id:number)
{
const pers=this.personnes.find(personneObject =>  personneObject.id === 
id) ;
return pers ;
}`

"My single-personnne.component.ts"
`export class SinglePersonneComponent implements OnInit {

personne =new Personne(0,'','','') ;

constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,
private personnesService:PersonnesService,
private router:Router) { }

ngOnInit() {   
const id=this.route.snapshot.params['id'] ;
this.personne = this.personnesService.getSinglePersonne(+id) ;
}`
```

"My template single-personnne.component.html"
    `

```
<div>
<h2>Nom :</h2>
<h3>{{personne.nom}}</h3>
</div>
<div>
<h2>Prénom :</h2>
<h3>{{personne.prenom}}</h3>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Numéro Téléphone:</h2>
    <h3>{{personne.numTel}}</h3>
</div>

 <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="updatePers()">Modifier</button>
```

`
I excpect to get a personne with the id=2 and want to display it in the template

Comment: What is the code for rendering the template? Probably you forget to pass the `personne` property.

Comment: You need safe navigation operator: `{{personne?.nom}}`

Comment: Can you be a little bit clear, i call the variable personne through {{}} on template ,like {{personne.nom}}

Comment: So i've already tried  this {{personne?.nom}} , the error dissapeared but there's nothing displayed on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your url `http://localhost:4200/Personnes/view/:2` your id is ':2', so the `+id` in `this.personnesService.getSinglePersonne(+id)` will resolve to `NaN`, so you will try to search for a person with `id === NaN` and that is always `false`. You should change your url to `http://localhost:4200/Personnes/view/2` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much ,it was the problem,and i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Your service method should look like this:

```
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/list`).pipe(
        map(res => {
            return res['data'];
        }),
        filter(person => person.id === id),
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

And component:

```
ngOnInit() {   
    const id=this.route.snapshot.params['id'] ;
    this.personnesService.getSinglePersonne(id).subscribe(person => this.personne = person);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,I've tried your code but still have nothing displayed on the template

Comment: The ? resolved the error but nothing on the template

Comment: Add the log to `map(res => { console.log(res);
            return res['data'];
        }),` and tell me what it shows.

Comment: I added the log an i got =>  {data: Array(10)}
data: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object

Comment: Please use http://jsonprettyprint.com/ or something, I can't see anything like this. Also add log here: `this.personnesService.getSinglePersonne(id).subscribe(person => {this.personne = person; console.log(person); });`

Comment: nothing appears when adding the "console.log(person)"  but the "console.log(res)" gives all the data from the server , it is like  {data: Array(10)}

Answer (score 0):

Your service method `getSinglePersonne` returns an empty `pers` for a particular `id`. There may be two reasons for this

1. Either the particular id doesn't exist in the array
2. Or the condition `personneObject.id === id` is causing the trouble. While it is always good practice to use `===`, but you may use `==` to verify if this is causing the issue.

Now since the service method doesn't return any matching object, `this.personne` remains *undefined* and hence the error you are facing.